# Outlook Mail Rest API message id repeating for different mails?

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-restapi

I am using outlook rest api to interact with my emails. I am storing my emails in a SQL database. The message response object has a filed called ID which according to the documentation is "The unique identifier of the message.". But I can see this id is same for multiple emails.

What is the exact behaviour of Id field??

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you're comparing them in a case-sensitive manner. They do not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

@ptwo There are two types of IDs, one of them is called 'ID', which is unique for every email, the other one is conversationID, which can be the same for the emails that are part of the same conversation (Reply, Reply All,...). You should not make ConversationID a primary key in your database table.